# Auto generate models on creation of other models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, has-many

I have a model called Video that has many statuses. I want to create a status of each kind and add it to @video.statuses in the def create of VideosController.

In VideosController, I have:

```
 def create
    @video = Video.new(params[:video])
    Kind.all.each do |f|
      @video.statuses.new(:kind =>f, :kind_id=>f.id,:comment =>"", :time_comp => nil, :completed =>false, :video_id =>@video.id)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @video, status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, this returns an error that says that the video could not be saved because the Statuses were invalid. The only validation in my entire project is in status and it merely checks that there is a video_id.
I'm very confused why I'm getting this error and would appreciate any help!

https://github.com/ninajlu/videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create the statuses before saving the @video, so it has no @video.id and thus is invalid following your validation rule

Answer (score 3):

Since Status depends on video already existing, you probably want to create the statuses after video is created.

You can either do this in a video callback, or in the controller. Something like:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @video.save
      Kind.all.each do |f|
        @video.statuses.create(:kind =>f, :kind_id=>f.id,:comment =>"", :time_comp => nil, :completed =>false, :video_id =>@video.id)
      end
      # respond as before
```

If you went the callback route, it would be:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_statuses

  def create_statuses
    Kind.all.each do |f|
      statuses.create(:kind =>f, :kind_id=>f.id,:comment =>"", :time_comp => nil, :completed =>false, :video_id => self.id)
    end
  end
```

And then you would not mention statuses in your controller -- you'd save as normally.

A final solution would be to use a Service object that coordinates the saving of statuses after creating the video. More at this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects)